# Why does this CAKeyFrameAnimation stop with zero opacity?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I have this code. At the end of the values array, you can see I provide 0.5 for the opacity. But for some reason, when the animation stops, it flashes once again and then leaves the view completely transparent. What's wrong there?

```
CALayer *layer = self.layer;
CAKeyframeAnimation *blinkAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
blinkAnim.duration = 1.0;
//blinkAnim.repeatCount = 0;
blinkAnim.autoreverses = NO;

// keyframe times and values
// we want to start fully opaque, fade out, stay faded out and fade back in shortly before the end of the cycle
blinkAnim.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.85],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
blinkAnim.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], nil];
[layer addAnimation:blinkAnim forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `fillMode` (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Fill_Modes)) for a `CAAnimation` is `kCAFillModeRemoved`. You should set the `fillMode` of your animation to `kCAFillModeForwards`, and also set the `removedOnCompletion` property to `NO` (by default it's `YES`):

```
blinkAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
blinkAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```

You'll notice that those properties were set in the source I wrote for your previous question -- they were there for a reason.