# how to animate navigationItem (blink or flash like)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, core-animation

I've got a scrollView app. And each scrollView item has it's own title (navigationItem title). Now when user does something(I have a way of capturing this event) on a particular scrollView item I want to animate the navigation item.

I was thinking maybe changing it's background color continuously or something or maybe better increase/decrease it's transparency if possible.

Has anyone done something similar to this? What would be the right approach to do this? I don't have a script requirement what I need to do, just that the current scrollView item(view) is different from others.

Thanks for any suggestions

I got it from the response I received :

```
CABasicAnimation *animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.duration=1.5;
    animation.repeatCount=1000000;
    animation.autoreverses=YES;
    animation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3];
    [button addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

it's not too fast and intensive to cause a seizure I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIBarButtonItem (annoyingly) does not inherit from UIView, so CoreAnimation would do diddly squat if you tried it.  However, if you rolled your own navigation item with a `UIButton` and a `UIImageView` set as the `customView` property, then animation is entirely possible with UIView's block animation wrapper:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    [myButton setAlpha:0.0f];
    //the button is now invisible
}];
```

As for color animations, unfortunately, only CGColors may be animated, and then, only under very sketchy circumstances.

Comment: thank you for the response, I was thinking of making it flash or something like that I'm still unsure what I want. How would I do that? Any links or explanation would be quite useful. thanks

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard if you want an alpha flash (1.0, 0.8, 1.0), to do it entirely with a CAKeyFrameAnimation.  Look that up, they're extremely powerful.

Comment: I'm sorry to bug you I have no previous experience with CAKeyFrameAnimation I was google-ing for some examples found some but not sure how to apply alpha flash as you suggest, could you point me to some examples of what you had in mind? thanks

Comment: No, they absolutely apply to alpha.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159736/why-does-this-cakeyframeanimation-stop-with-zero-opacity)

Comment: You can animate alpha using UIView animation. The docs for UIView say that a view's color (A UIColor) can be animated as well. It should be pretty straightforward to do a color change using UIView animation without resorting to CAKeyframeAnimation. Keyframe animations are indeed powerful, but CAAnimations are much harder to figure out (and much more poorly documented) than UIView block animations.

Comment: @DuncanC: It may be animateable, but I've had far too many terrible experiences with UIBarbuttonItem's in the past to even attempt any kind of discernible animation.  Better yet, avoid the things altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following instead of trying to animate the entire button..
For blink or flash like animation for navigation item, you can just change its tintColor

```
  // call timer where you want to start the blinking or flash like animation

 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.65f target:self selector:@selector(animate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


 -(void)animate
  {

   if (flagAnimate == 0) {
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
     flagAnimate = 1;
  }
   else if (flagAnimate == 1)
  {
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
     flagAnimate = 0;

  }
```

Comment: does not work if the barItem is built with an image and not a text